# public static non-inner class in Java?

Tags: java, android, class, static

as far as I've researched around, a static class in Java only makes sense if it's an inner class.

But I just came across this example and I want to understand what the author meant, what it does, and how it works:

from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

```
    public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        // a normal class with public constructor and TabListener methods
        ...
    }
```

what static means here and why should it work?
and why is him extending Fragment with `<T >` ? instead of the normal way.

thanks!

**edit:**
wow, that was a lot of answers very quickly.
thanks all who shared their knowledge here.

I'll mark @npe answer as the correct one as he correctly pointed out that the text around the example indicates that this class is a member.

also there's some weird formatting on stack overflow that I just fixed on my original question and repeat here:
and why is him extending Fragment with `<T >` ?

and @Ahmad answered that one, but I can't mark two correct answers.

Comment: this class definitely must be inner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to declare member class as `static` - it will issue a compiler error.
And your example **is** about an member class - quoting [the page you linked to](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):

> For example, here's how you might implement the [ActionBar.TabListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html) such that each tab uses its own instance of the listener:

So the page states, that the `TabListener` *is a member class*.

Comment: An inner class is non static by definition. You mean a nested class.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1), in the context of a class:

> The modifier static pertains only to member classes (§8.5.1), not to top level or local or anonymous classes.

So the code you show can only be a nested class, it can't be a top level class.

Also note that inner classes are non-static nested classes, so a static class can't be an inner class, only a nested class.

Answer (score 1):

```
what static means here and why should it work?
```

**You need an instance of enclosing class if you doesn't make inner class static.**.

well, Listeners are particular to some classes usually...so for the sake of cohesion it's good to have them in the class itself.

```
why is him extending Fragment with
```

tablistener must be expecting an object in itslelf which must be subtype of Fragement. read about **Generics** to explore more.

Answer (score 1):

This class definitely must be inner.
Whats about the question mark, it's just a generic type. It means that this class uses some type which extends Fragment type. When using this class, you simply say `new TabListener<SomeTypeExtendingFragment>()`

Answer (score 1):

Usually when we implement a listener we use `this`. In this case, though, they created an *inner* class for the listener that is specific to a particular `Tab`. Static class means it is accessed and created directly instead of through creating an instance of the parent class, so you see they instantiate the `TabListener` directly. It is also an independent entity, so it looks as if it were an independent class. (In fact, you can define it without `static` in another file.)

Answer (score 0):

The class is inner. The keyword `static` is only allowed for inner classes.